# 5.5K to a Real Number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

I'm trying to convert a lot of data points in a more efficient way from .7K, 3.2K, 2.25M, etc. into a real number format. I know there is a way to create custom number formats but how do I do that when there are so many IF statements that would be in play. I don't really know where to start and any help would be appreciated. I know I can use the filter and replace tool to work through each if statement individually but as there and thousands of data points I want to find a more effective way.

[image]

Comment: You say so many if statements, what other combinations are there?  Are K and M the only ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add all the different combination of characters in the lookup.

If a particular character is not found in the lookup, the result will be N/A.

`=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(C2,1),G2:H3,2)*SUBSTITUTE(C2,RIGHT(C2,1),"")`

[image]

Tip: When you drag/fill the formula the reference of the vlookup also changes, to avoid that add '$' to cell reference.

`=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(C2,1),$G$2:$H$3,2)*SUBSTITUTE(C2,RIGHT(C2,1),"")`

Answer (score 2):

If it is just the two; K and M, then the following will do what you want:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) * IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("k",A1)),1000,1000000)
```

[image]

---

To do it in place with vba:

```
Sub foooooooo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet12") ' Change to your worksheet name

    With ws
        'Change the "A" to the column in which you have the numbers and the 1 to the first row of numbers
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        rng.Value = .Evaluate("=INDEX(LEFT(" & rng.Address & ",LEN(" & rng.Address & ")-1) * IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""k""," & rng.Address & ")),1000,1000000),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Will that loop through the entire column if its selected?

Comment: No you would put the formula in B1 and copy/fill it down.  The reference will automatically change. @MayaCat